# Is it possible to create to create a Tkinter subwindow?

Tags: python, tkinter

Everything is in the question, and how can I do that ?
When I say a subwindow I mean a floating window in a main window.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Creating subwindows in general is super easy. You do it by reading a tkinter tutorial. Are you saying that you want to restrict the subwindow to always stay inside the main window? That's more tricky.

Comment: Yes, i want my subwindow always in the main window... :/